# Get Last Column in Bootstrap Row via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web app that uses jQuery and Bootstrap. The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row ui-row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ui-col" data-row="1" data-col="1">
      Test 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ui-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col" data-row="3" data-col="1">
      Test 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col">
      <div class="design cmenu" data-id="86">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col" data-row="3" data-col="3">
      Test 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 my-col" data-row="3" data-col="4">
      Test 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(".ui-row")
    .mouseover(function () {
      console.log($(this));
    })
  ;
</script>
```

When a user hovers over a `ui-row`, I want to grab the last `ui-col` in the row via jQuery. However, I'm not sure who to do that. Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to find the descendant element then use :[last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector) to find the last one. Also you might want to use [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) instead of [mouseover](https://api.jquery.com/mouseover)(otherwise when you move within `ui-row` also the event will be triggered)

```js
$(".ui-row").mouseenter(function() {
  snippet.log($(this).find('.ui-col:last').text());
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<div id="container">
  <div class="row ui-row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ui-col" data-row="1" data-col="1">
      Test 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ui-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col" data-row="3" data-col="1">
      Test 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col">
      <div class="design cmenu" data-id="86">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col" data-row="3" data-col="3">
      Test 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 my-col" data-row="3" data-col="4">
      Test 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)** to get **[`.ui-col`](https://api.jquery.com/last/)** div's, then to get the last one use `last()` method

```js
$(".ui-row").mouseover(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('.ui-col').last().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="row ui-row">
    <div class="col-md-12 ui-col" data-row="1" data-col="1">
      Test 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ui-row">
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col" data-row="3" data-col="1">
      Test 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col">
      <div class="design cmenu" data-id="86">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ui-col" data-row="3" data-col="3">
      Test 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 my-col" data-row="3" data-col="4">
      Test 4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```